# Is it possible to make Vscode IntelliSense exstension that writes automatically in certain cases?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-extensions

I am wondering if it is possible to make an exstension which automatically writes a `\n end`(were \n is an escape) when the line starts with `if`  so when `if` is writen in the editor and a space is made after the `if` it will always automatically paste `\n end` in the editor. If so where can I read about the commands I need to have the exstension write to the editor?

Maybe such exstension already exist but I have had no luck finding such an exstension. It not only for `if` statements I am looking to do this but also for `for` and `while` statements ect.

Comment: The HyperSnips extension already does this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You should look into the [`TextDocumentChangeEvent`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextDocumentChangeEvent) which can be subscribed to from `onDidChangeTextDocument`.

Then you can analyze the contentChanges and see if it matches the `if` pattern you want. If it does you can use the [`TextEdit`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEdit) API to perform the insertion of the newlines